# Swift & Firebase - Delete hashtags from post

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashtag, swift4

I'm trying to code the function to delete a post in my app. When I delete a post, I would like to delete also all the hashtags related to that post.
I'm using Firebase, not for a long time and I don't really know how to do that :/

This is my DataBase: 
[image]

I have every "hashtags" and in the child, the posts associated.

When I delete a post, I would like to delete the child associated from hashtags.

This is my unfinished code:

```
func deleteHashtagsFromPost(withPost id: String) {
      Database.database().reference().child("hashtag").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
         if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {

            for hashtag in dict {
               // Here I can access to the hashtag with hashtag.key
               // And also to the children associated with hashtag.value
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

This is an insight of "Posts" in my DataBase:

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with Firebase Cloud Functions? You can create an event listener that deletes the post from its corresponding hashtags.

Comment: Could tell me more about that function ?

Comment: Well firstly this function I am referring to would live in the Cloud. You write the code locally in js and deploy the code using Firebase's CLI. However, it may still be suitable for you to delete the posts in Swift too.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your posts? How do they look?

Comment: @Callam I edited my post for you.

Answer (score 0):

In noSQL database like Firebase is based on, the best practice is to duplicate your objects.

Your tags initially belong to the posts associated, so put them in here. It will be easy to display them in your app as they are in the object you retrieve. You probably also want to search the posts based on tags, so you create a tags branch like you did, that way you can get all posts related without having to search in each posts for the tag.

This may seems redundant, but this is how it works in noSQL, you have to handle multiple places for you datas if you want better results.

You might know that but if your data model has a lot of relationships, it could be better to go for an SQL database. (your model as it is doesn't have much, so it's ok)

> Vive la baguette !

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that inside your post you aren't storing the hashtags. So in order to delete them you'd have to loop over the whole hashtag branch which you don't want to do on the client side. I'd store the hashtags in the post object. Then do this

```
let hashtags = [String]() // put all the posts hashtags in here
let postKey = post.key // key for the post you just deleted

for i in 0..<hashtags.count {
    deleteHashtagsFromPost(postKey: postKey, hashtagUsedInPost: hashtags[i])
}

func deleteHashtagsFromPost(postKey: String, hashtagUsedInPost: String) {
    Database.database().reference.child("hashtag").child(hashtagUsedInPost).child(postKey).removeValue()
    // you can add a completion block if you wish
}
```

If you're interested in using a Firebase cloud function it could look something like this:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// so we can write to the database in functions outside of the database triggers
var db = admin.database();

exports.deleteHastags = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postid}').onDelete(event => { 

  console.log("Post was deleted");
  const key = event.data.previous.key;
  const post = event.data.previous.val();
  const hashtags = event.data.previous.val().hashtags; // requires that the hashtags are stored with the post in FB DB
  removeHashtags(hashtags, key);
  return;
});

function removeHashtags(hashtags, key) {
    for (var hashtag in hashtags) {
        db.ref("hashtag").child(hashtag).child(key).remove();
    }
}
```

[Firebase Database Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)